# can i make layers selection and automatic filling with those i dragged from gallery into photo shop with the help of java script

Tags: photoshop-script

i found a lot of scripts but ....those are not good to use .. i have more requirements . I am Able to select layers with the help of javascript but the problem is layers are not getting filled with dragged  images

if (app.documents.length > 0) {

activeDocument.suspendHistory('stuff', 'main()');

function main(){

if(!documents.length) return;

var myDoc = app.activeDocument;

var theName = myDoc.activeLayer.name;

var theResults = new Array;

selectAllLayers();

var selectedLayers = getSelectedLayersIdx();

for(var a = 0; a < selectedLayers.length; a++){

var thisName = layerName(Number(selectedLayers[a]));

if (thisName == theName) {

```
      theResults.push(Number(selectedLayers[a]))

      };
```

};

selectLayerByIndex(theResults[0], false);

for (var m = 1; m < theResults.length; m++) {

selectLayerByIndex(theResults[m], true);

};

}

};

function getSelectedLayersIdx(){

```
       var selectedLayers = new Array;

       var ref = new ActionReference();

       ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID("Dcmn"), charIDToTypeID("Ordn"), charIDToTypeID("Trgt") );

       var desc = executeActionGet(ref);

       if( desc.hasKey( stringIDToTypeID( 'targetLayers' ) ) ){

                 desc = desc.getList( stringIDToTypeID( 'targetLayers' ));

                  var c = desc.count

                  var selectedLayers = new Array();

                  for(var i=0;i<c;i++){

                           try{

                                     activeDocument.backgroundLayer;

                                     selectedLayers.push(  desc.getReference( i ).getIndex() );

                           }catch(e){

                                     selectedLayers.push(  desc.getReference( i ).getIndex()+1 );

                           }

                  }

        }else{

                 var ref = new ActionReference();

                 ref.putProperty( charIDToTypeID("Prpr") , charIDToTypeID( "ItmI" ));

                 ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID("Lyr "), charIDToTypeID("Ordn"), charIDToTypeID("Trgt") );

                 try{

                           activeDocument.backgroundLayer;

                           selectedLayers.push( executeActionGet(ref).getInteger(charIDToTypeID( "ItmI" ))-1);

                 }catch(e){

                           selectedLayers.push( executeActionGet(ref).getInteger(charIDToTypeID( "ItmI" )));

                 }

       }

       return selectedLayers;
```

};

function selectAllLayers() {

var desc29 = new ActionDescriptor();

```
      var ref23 = new ActionReference();

      ref23.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt') );
```

desc29.putReference( charIDToTypeID('null'), ref23 );

executeAction( stringIDToTypeID('selectAllLayers'), desc29, DialogModes.NO );

};

function layerName(idx){

var ref = new ActionReference();

ref.putIndex( charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ), idx);

var desc = executeActionGet(ref);

return desc.getString(stringIDToTypeID("name"));

};

function selectLayerByIndex(index,add){

add = undefined ? add = false:add

var ref = new ActionReference();

```
ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID("Lyr "), index);

var desc = new ActionDescriptor();

desc.putReference(charIDToTypeID("null"), ref );

   if(add) desc.putEnumerated( stringIDToTypeID( "selectionModifier" ), stringIDToTypeID( "selectionModifierType" ), stringIDToTypeID( "addToSelection" ) );

  desc.putBoolean( charIDToTypeID( "MkVs" ), false );
```

try{

```
executeAction(charIDToTypeID("slct"), desc, DialogModes.NO );
```

}catch(e){

alert(e.message);

}